# How do I read a text file then place the data using a separator line?

Tags: c#, file-io, streamreader

```
private void open(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openDialog.FileName);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(text);
        }

    }
}
```

So in this code I can read a text file but I can only do as if it's on 1 grid. Here is what a sample text file will look like:

```
test,1,2,3,4,5,6,
testing,7,8,9,10,11,12,
working,13,14,15,16,17,18,
multiline,19,20,21,22,23,24,
NEXTDATA
see,25,26,36,46,56,66,
program,7,8,9,10,11,12,
macroer,13,14,15,16,17,18,
readextra,19,20,21,22,23,24,
```

So if I reach the line called "NEXTDATA" it I want that data to be put in `dataGridView2`. How do I check if it reaches that line and then it will do the same thing as the code in `dataGridView1`?

Also do I use `ReadLine()` or `ReadAllLines()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
var targetGridView = dataGridView1;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line == "NEXTDATA") 
    {
        targetGridView = dataGridView2;
        continue;
    }

    var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
    targetGridView.Rows.Add(text);
}
```

Or in case you need to switch back and forth between `dataGridView1` and `dataGridView2`, try this:

```
var targetGridView = dataGridView1;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line == "NEXTDATA") 
    {
        targetGridView = (targetGridView == dataGridView1) 
            ? dataGridView2 : dataGridView1;
        continue;
    }

    var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
    targetGridView.Rows.Add(text);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to post this! :D

Comment: Ohhh.. so close to being identical to mine.

Comment: Thanks. Tested it and it works. Also thanks to the rest who tried to help too! :)

Answer (score 5):

Store a reference to the `GridView` you want to add to.. then just flip it as required:

```
var currentGridView = dataGridView1;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line == "NEXTDATA") {
        currentGridView = dataGridView2;
        continue;
    }

    var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
    currentGridView.Rows.Add(text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openDialog.FileName);

    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if(line == "NEXTDATA")
        {
            dgv = dataGridView2;
            continue;
        }

        var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
        dgv.Rows.Add(text);
    }
```

> Also do I use `ReadLine()` or `ReadAllLines()`?

That's up to you - `ReadLine` reads one line, `ReadAllLines` reads the entire file into an array of strings, so you either loop, calling `ReadLine` each time, or call `ReadAllLines` and loop over the array.